# BOOTSTRAP 4: How to overlap images using unordered list?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

*I will try to be straightforward as possible.*

I am trying to remake this web design.
**REREFERENCE**: https://cdn.dribbble.com/userupload/4110574/file/original-c8fb153f632b18510bb3980b2e6705ca.jpg?resize=1600x1200

But I cannot overlap the images.
[image]

How can I overlap the images using unordered list?

**CODE**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Trial</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Font: Noto Sans Tai Lue (400, 500, 600, 700) -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+New+Tai+Lue:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body class="">



    <!-- Navbar Start -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-dark bg-white py-4 px-5 font-weight-bold" style="font-family: 'Noto Sans New Tai Lue', sans-serif;">
        <a class="navbar-brand ml-5" href="#"><img src="./images/logo.png" width="150px"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span><img src="./images/hamburger.png" width="25px"></span>
            </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse p-2 pb-4" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-3 align-items-xl-center" style="font-size: 20px;">
                <li class="nav-item active mr-lg-5">
                    <a class="nav-link" style="color: #fdb24b;" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mr-lg-5">
                    <a class="nav-link" style="color: #305252;" href="#">Testimonial</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mr-lg-5">
                    <a class="nav-link" style="color: #305252;" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mr-lg-5">
                    <a class="nav-link" style="color: #305252;" href="#">Sign In</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mt-lg-4 mt-xl-0 mr-lg-5">
                    <a class="text-white py-lg-3 px-lg-4 py-xl-4 px-xl-5 rounded-pill" style="background-color: #fd5347;" href="#">Sign Up</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Navbar End -->



    <!-- Banner Start -->
    <section class="container-fluid p-5" style="background-color: #22264b; height: 85vh;">
        <!-- Text -->
        <div class="col-xl-6 row p-5 h-100">
            <div class="col-xl-12 p-0">
                <h5 class="display-6 font-weight-bold" style="color: #fdb24b; font-family: 'Noto Sans New Tai Lue', sans-serif;">100% SATISFACTION GUARANTEE</h5>
                <h1 class="text-white display-3 font-weight-normal" style="font-family: 'Noto Sans New Tai Lue', sans-serif;">
                    Get Quality <strong>tutoring</strong><br> 
                    <strong>Through 1-on-1</strong><br> 
                    Online Tutoring
                </h1>

                <h5 class="text-white mt-5 display-5 lh-sm">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing alit, sed do eiupmod<br>
                ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</h5>
            </div>

            <!-- Join Us Link -->
            <div class="col-xl-12 d-flex align-items-center p-0">
                <div class="col-xl-4">
                    <!-- Button -->
                    <button class="text-white py-4 rounded-pill border-0 h-25 font-weight-bold" style="background-color: #fd5347; font-size: 20px; width: 225px;">Join Us</button>
                </div>

                <!-- Users -->
                <div class="col-xl-5">
                    <ul class="list-group list-unstyled list-group-horizontal d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <li><img class="rounded-circle" src="./images/user1.png" width="75px"></li>
                            <li><img class="rounded-circle" src="./images/user2.png" width="75px"></li>
                            <li><img class="rounded-circle" src="./images/user3.png" width="75px"></li>
                            <li><img class="rounded-circle" src="./images/user4.png" width="75px"></li>
                            <li><img class="rounded-circle" src="./images/user5.png" width="75px"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <!-- Users Amount Joined -->
                <div class="col-xl-3 text-white">
                    <h4>
                        12,020 also joined us
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Banner End -->



    <!-- Main Start -->
    <main>
        <!-- Universities Start -->
        <section>
            <h5>Collaboration with Various Top Universities</h5>

            <ul>
                <li><img src=""></li>
                <li><img src=""></li>
                <li><img src=""></li>
                <li><img src=""></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <!-- Universities End -->
    </main>
    <!-- Main End -->


    <!-- Bootstrap Script -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

My idea is to use something that's a reverse of the ***gap*** (gap adds spaces in between) and code it so that it will allow to overlap. I tried reading and fixing it for about 90 minutes, but I still do not have the idea on how I will do it.

Comment: Please do not use your Google drive to show us your code. The code should be in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You might change the content of your Google drive, and your question will be incomprehensible to future readers in the years to come. Learning how to ask a question correctly will increase your chance of getting good answers.

Comment: `position: relative; left: -20px`

Comment: Or use `col-[size]-[pull|push]-X` classes

Comment: @Justinas Hello, where should I add them? I am quite a beginner on this.